# The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony

I have created a registration form.
But when I submit I have the following error message

> The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given

here is my controller

```
  public function connexion(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder) {

            // get the login error if there is one
            $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
            // last username entered by the user
            $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

            // 1) build the form
            $user              = new User();
            $form_registration = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user);

            // 2) handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
            $form_registration->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form_registration->isSubmitted() && $form_registration->isValid()) {

                // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
                $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
                $user->setPassword($password);

                // 4) save the User!
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                // ... do any other work - like sending them an email, etc
                // maybe set a "flash" success message for the user

                return $this->redirectToRoute('connexion');
            }

            return $this->render('connexion.html.twig', array(
                'form_registration' => $form_registration->createView(),
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,));
        }
```

my html

```
{{ form_start(form_registration) }}
{{ form_row(form_registration.username) }}
{{ form_row(form_registration.email) }}
{{ form_row(form_registration.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_row(form_registration.plainPassword.second) }}

<button type="submit">Register!</button>
{{ form_end(form_registration) }}
```

Do you know why I have this error message?

Normally when I fill in my username I should not have it.

I don't have copy paste my RegistrationType but it is ok I have tested it in a previous RegistrationController and it worked perfectly..

here is my Ctrl-u result

```
<section class="section-main-inscription_rapide">
    <h3>INSCRIPTION GRATUITE</h3>
    <form name="registration" method="post">
    <div><label for="registration_username" class="required">Username</label><input type="text" id="registration_username" name="registration[username]" required="required" /></div>
    <div><label for="registration_email" class="required">Email</label><input type="email" id="registration_email" name="registration[email]" required="required" /></div>
    <div><label for="registration_plainPassword_first" class="required">Password</label><input type="password" id="registration_plainPassword_first" name="registration[plainPassword][first]" required="required" /></div>
    <div><label for="registration_plainPassword_second" class="required">Repeat Password</label><input type="password" id="registration_plainPassword_second" name="registration[plainPassword][second]" required="required" /></div>

    <button type="submit">Register!</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="registration__token" name="registration[_token]" value="xQ6gADeUkUb424-2ccvtyXd_atle7dYCPW0OLTefI_g" /></form>
</section>
```

My security.yaml:

```
    form_login:
        login_path: connexion
        check_path: connexion
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use ctrl-u in your browser to view the generated html source of your login form.  The problem will be obvious.  For the solution, search for how to customize the username and password element names for the form_login section of your security config file.

Comment: I have updated my Ctrl-u results

Comment: Post the form_login section of your security file.  It looks like the registration form is posting to the check_login route.  And you really should have an action attribute in your html form element.

Comment: I have posted it

Comment: So when you post your registration form it is being intercepted by check_login which thinks your are trying to login.  You need to setup a registration route.

Comment: Ok I  try it ! thanks

Comment: What does `RegistrationType` look like?

Comment: @Cerad how can I unclude a form in my login page. Because at the beginning I did that, i created a registration page and controller and it worked perfectly. But what I want, is to include my registration form in my login page. I can create the form at the hand with the specific action attribute it will work i think but I would like to use the power of symfony without creating  my form at the hand

Comment: It's ok instead of creating a new registration route, I have changed my check_login path to another route and I can keep my registration form in my login page. Thanks @Cerad

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html for setting a different action just for the registration form.  This should allow both login and registration to peacefully co-exist on the same page.  You still need to define a registration route.

Comment: Ok @Cerad you're right. I didn't see that we had the possibility to define action for our form when we build it... So I have created registration road now it's cool:) Thank you:)

Comment: @Chausser Sorry I reply too late. My Registration Type was the same than https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html

Answer (score 9):

form_login has these 2 options

```
            username_parameter: "login_form[username]"
            password_parameter: "login_form[password]"
```

By default these are set to _username and _password, so you either have to change the field names to _username and _password or change the security.yml file username_parameter and password_parameter to your field names.

Answer (score 2):

Or in your form class you can override the method 'getBlockPrefix()' and make it return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name in the input from **registration[username]** to `_username`

```html
<input type="text" id="registration_username" name="_username" required="required" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.
In security.yml if you modify the 'login-path' and 'check_path'
make sure that the route in the 'UserController' (the one that deals the login process) with the login route has the same naming.
ex:login_path: admin_login
check_path: admin_login
and same route for login the controller

and then, the one that must be checked is the constant variable in the Authenticator
LOGIN_ROUTE = 'admin_login'. that fixed it for me. It had the default route so i had the error because of that.

btw: no need to change the name's input in the login form for 'username'. By 'email' it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, "t0.is_valid column not found" and it was the RegistrationFormType that has NOT BLANK constraints which cause that problem

Before:

```
->add("name", null, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Write your name'
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'max' => 45,
                        'maxMessage' => 'Too large ( {{ limit }} max)'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
```

After:

```
->add("name", null, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'max' => 45,
                        'maxMessage' => 'Too large ( {{ limit }} max)'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
```

And my symfony login works again