# Symfony 4 - The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given

Tags: php, symfony, identifier

my project symfony 4 I have a function that serves me for authentication but also for registration:

```
/**
     * Login
     *
     * @Route("/login", name="account_login")
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login2(AuthenticationUtils $utils, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        // Connexion
        $error = $utils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $username = $utils->getLastUsername();

        // Inscription
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
            $user->setHash($password);
            $manager->persist($user);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Votre compte a bien été créé ! Vous pouvez maintenant vous connecter'
            );

            $this->redirectToRoute('account_login');
        }


        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'hasError' => $error !== null,
            'username' => $username,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

So in my twig file I have my login form:

```
<form id="login-form" action="{{path('account_login')}}" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="_username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email" required value={{username}}>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
         <input type="password" name="_password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe">
     </div>
</form>
```

And my registration form :

```
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_widget(form)}}
{{form_end(form)}}
```

But when I submit my registration form, I've this error :

> The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given.

In my security.yml I've :

```
form_login:
        login_path: account_login
        check_path: account_login
        default_target_path: absence_index

      logout:
        path: account_logout
        target: account_login
```

I found this post : [The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056138/the-key-username-must-be-a-string-null-given-symfony-4)

It's the same problem I think, but I don't understand what's the solution.

Comment: Have you chekhed if the variable `value={{username}}` is not null ?

Comment: I tried this, but same problem

Comment: I think it happen because even when you submit your registration form, symfony try to listen to your login form (according to your security.yml configuration) and then sometime the username variable (come from $utils->getLastUsername();) can be null if there was not previous authentication. So could you try to separate registration and login in two actions controller with different route path. If you want you can render their form in the same view but you must put different form action attribute depending on registration or login.

Comment: Okay, I separated my two actions, it works better, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mixing login and registration on *one route* is weird ... and I'm quite sure it won't work (without much hassle that is), because the framework already handles the request. (as in: it has some "form" that handles the request and produces errors)

However, you don't actually have to put it on one route ... just set the `action` on the registration and login form to the appropriate route and use the same templates.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i juste had to make sure that "getLoginUrl" in "class WsEdupoleAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator" is return